# Stored procedure always returns false

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures

This Stored Procedure should be returning a false if the value passed in the parameter does not exist in the table.

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`listsjag_user`@`%` PROCEDURE `Select_ReferenceAvailability`(IN ref VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM tbl_dataLibrary
WHERE itemreference = @ref
) THEN
SELECT 'true';
ELSE
SELECT 'false';
END IF;

      END
```

It is returning true for all values but there is only one value in the column itemreference.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Change `@ref` to `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL stored procedure cannot really *return* a value. You can either pass in an OUT parameter and modify it, or convert your procedure to a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReferenceAvailability (IN ref VARCHAR(45)) 
RETURNS boolean 
BEGIN 
 IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl_dataLibrary WHERE itemreference = @ref)) THEN 
   RETURN 1; 
 END IF; 

RETURN 0; 
END;
```

I changed your true/false to 1/0, feel free to change back, but you will need to return varchar(5).

Use the function in a select like this:

```
SELECT ReferenceAvailability(...)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You overlooked the discrepancy between the parameter `ref` and the user-defined variable `@ref`.  Those are two different namespaces in two different scopes (program vs. session), so your answer is also incorrect.   Also, stored procedures can return resultsets, and can have `OUT` or `INOUT` parameters.